# VirtualBox won't open on Mac OS HighSierra

Tags: macos, virtualbox

I've been having some issues lately with my virtualbox. I tried reinstalling it but it won't help.
I don't get why my VB suddenly stopped working and won't start.
I tried looking if it has anything to do with permissions but I am not an expert in reading the following: Is it problem with permission ?

```
 drwxr-xr-x@  30 root           wheel      960 Oct 15 09:19 /
 drwxr-xr-x+  60 milicamiletic  admin     1920 Oct 15 10:01 /Applications
 0: group:everyone deny delete
 drwxr-xr-x    3 root           admin       96 Oct 15 10:01 /Applications/VirtualBox.app
-rw-r--r--    1 root           admin  5529952 Aug 14 14:04 /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxRT.dylib
drwxr-xr-x    6 root           wheel      192 Nov 13  2017 /private
drwxr-xr-x  118 root           wheel     3776 Oct 15 09:36 /private/etc
-r--r-----    1 root           wheel     1563 Dec 11  2016 /private/etc/sudoers
drwxrwxrwt    8 root           wheel      256 Oct 15 10:01 /private/tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually applications are installed *not* as root but as the user. you seem to have installed VirtualBox as root. 
Moreover, it seems you are missing the main executable file.
Try reinstalling virtualbox as yourself

Comment: Thanks for the answer Koko, but it won't fix by reinstalling